# Setting fields in the database using setters in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have two entities mapped with @OneToOne relationships.
So, User has a foreignKey field to Transaction.
If I want to set a field in the transaction, can I do it using UserRepository?

```
User user=userRepository.findOne(long id ) // find the user with that id

user.getTransactions().setNumber(6); ? //getTransactions is the field that is mapped to Transactions
```

Number is a field in transactions.
Or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understend what do you want. You want to use `userRepository` to update `Transactions` object. I think that's possible but you have to use `Cascade` mode.

You can find here more informations about it :

https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/